# Play YouTube playlist automatically

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api

The code under here is to get automatic the most recent video in the iframe. It returns a playlist with the most recent video as the first video.

`<iframe play src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UnboxTherapy"& width="2000" height="1160"></iframe>`

Now I want to let the first video play automatically. The code to play a YouTube video automatically:

`?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1`

If you combine the 2 you get this:

`<iframe play src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UnboxTherapy?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1& width="2000" height="1160"></iframe>`

When you place the code above on your website the video will load and work properly, but the automatic play function doesn't work. It won't play automatic.

**Update after 2 years**

Now 2 years later after asking this question there is still no answer. I think it is not possible. Maybe in the future...

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

its possible

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries
?list=PL8J9oi-nz2_XrCc7e1v8qbECudibLOvpT"
frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay;
encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: replace  PL8J9oi-nz2_XrCc7e1v8qbECudibLOvpT with the end part thing of  playlist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

According to web resources to make a video automatically play on page load, you simply have to add

> ?autoplay=1

to the end of the url, this worked for me. But assuming you tried this, I'm inclined to think you are having a permissions error, and either your network admin or web browser is currently restricting auto playing videos. Please feel free to look at this link if you are using windows 7, or a similar link if not.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/autoplay-wont-work/69ac674b-ef1b-491d-9be2-f7a1d675956c

Comment: He's trying to make a user uploads playlist autoplay, not just a video. It's not working for me either.