# Embed users latest YouTube video with autoplay via iframe

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

While several questions of embedding a single video with autoplay have been answered here, embedding a users latest video seems not to work with the autoplay option.

Single video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/ln3wAdRAim4?start=126&controls=1&showinfo=1&rel=0&autoplay=1
```

Users latest video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=TheLateLateShow&controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1
```

Any advice?

Comment: Duplicate of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861916/play-youtube-video-automatic

Comment: And on my question there is no answer in 5 months time, so I think that there is no option for this!

Comment: @Arendax Thanks for the hint. No search or algorithm brought this up. Sad to see that 5 months have passed since your question. Watching it anyway.

Comment: I hope there is an answer to this too, lets see and hope for the best =) @matt